# Python Scrape Twitter Using API GraphQL Get Duplicate Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, request

I want to pull twitter post data using graphql api. I have created the code, but the code I created still produces many duplicate results. I don't know where my code is wrong.

Here is the flow of pulling twitter post data:

1. I first retrieve the data using module request with GET method with the following url https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/ukD99BOU37OlcBLMSDFRvQ/SearchTimeline, by bringing variables and features parameters. The variables parameter contains the variables "rawQuery": tag_name, "count": 20, "querySource": "recent_search_click", and "product": "Top".
2. I want to pull the second, third, and so on data using the module request with the GET method with the following url https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/ukD99BOU37OlcBLMSDFRvQ/SearchTimeline. Almost the same as point 1, but has a difference in the parameters that are brought, which is the addition of the cursor parameter. The cursor parameter will be filled with the value of the first data retrieval response which in the json response has the key value of the cursor.

On twitter to retrieve the next page data using the cursor parameter. Every 1 time a get request only gets 20 tweet data. To get tweet data on the next page, it is necessary that the url condition will change after the first get request or in other words get the cursor value from the previous request which is used to pull the next page data. From the output that I get the cursor value is always the same every iteration does not change, which should have a different cursor value for each iteration.

Here's the code I've created, but it still produces incorrect output.

```py
@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=RATE_LIMIT, period=TIME_PERIOD)
def get_twitter_data(tag_name):
    list_data_twitter = []

    base_url = 'https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/ukD99BOU37OlcBLMSDFRvQ/SearchTimeline'

    headers = {
        'Host': 'twitter.com',
        'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not;A=Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="106"',
        'X-Twitter-Client-Language': 'en',
        'X-Csrf-Token': 'f7f1e0d8436655a7e660bce8ddef222544e1e37b2aa6aaeb240dfe5d2c6296939f330ec8a9cce33a7da48a9b68c57135379480147d5654d6b05de6245df604ceffe9f43c798ce52f424cfec13f5e6e77',
        'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.5249.62 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Twitter-Auth-Type': 'OAuth2Session',
        'X-Twitter-Active-User': 'yes',
        'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Referer': f'https://twitter.com/search?q={tag_name}&src=recent_search_click',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1471152852.1686887303; _gid=GA1.2.76416245.1687922179; guest_id=v1%3A168792218525478935; _twitter_sess=BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCD9GAgCJAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlN2UwOGIyZTQwZjdlNzQxYjI5ZTE4ZjQyMDViZmNjMDg6B2lkIiVjYmY5%250AMDBmN2ZhNjRkYTU3ZTJlZWMxOGJmOTVkMzg4OQ%253D%253D--8b4314f08ed3e59601e46b9a3c15d987fce8293d; kdt=zmWUmVtp9onKvVoQzXFoWkeAHizyr5Ov1jMvvBKg; auth_token=57fc8361abf27dcad90ac37adadd115fdb5a7d5f; ct0=f7f1e0d8436655a7e660bce8ddef222544e1e37b2aa6aaeb240dfe5d2c6296939f330ec8a9cce33a7da48a9b68c57135379480147d5654d6b05de6245df604ceffe9f43c798ce52f424cfec13f5e6e77; lang=en; twid=u%3D1655651882877227008; att=1-YMW6i0j99UXPqCO4Gpvz5TrP9K65rRlhkaBiN2qo; guest_id_marketing=v1%3A168792218525478935; guest_id_ads=v1%3A168792218525478935; personalization_id="v1_MeR9tzAw7QrAvwf9Afl4og=="; guest_id=v1%3A168792288782936057; guest_id_ads=v1%3A168792288782936057; guest_id_marketing=v1%3A168792288782936057; personalization_id="v1_xRyToVk+kG9/lR0cFvnhDw=="'
    }

    cursor = None
    limit = 100

    while True:        
        var = {
            "rawQuery": tag_name, 
            "count": 20, 
            "querySource": "recent_search_click",
            "product": "Top"
        }
        
        if cursor is not None:
            var['cursor'] = cursor
        
        params = {
            'variables': json.dumps(var),
            'features': FEATURES_TWITTER,
        }
        
            
        try:
            response.raise_for_status()
            data = response.json()
        except requests.HTTPError as e:
            if e.response.status_code == 429:
                print("Too Many Requests. Sleeping for a while...")
                time.sleep(60)  
                continue
            else:
                print(f"HTTPError: {str(e)}")
                break
        except requests.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(f"JSONDecodeError: {str(e)}")
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
            break
        
        print("Request URL:", response.url)
        
        result = data.get("data", {}).get("search_by_raw_query", {})
        timeline = result.get("search_timeline", {}).get("timeline", {}).get("instructions", {})
        entries = [x.get("entries") for x in timeline if x.get("type") == "TimelineAddEntries"]
        entries = entries[0] if entries else []
        
        for entry in entries:
            entry_id = entry.get("entryId")
            content = entry.get("content")
            entry_type = content.get("entryType")
            if entry_id and not entry_id.startswith("promoted-tweet"):
                if entry_type == "TimelineTimelineItem":
                    tweet_results = content.get("itemContent", {}).get("tweet_results", {})
                    row_data = extract_row_data_post(tweet_results)
                    list_data_twitter.append(row_data)    

                if entry_type == "TimelineTimelineCursor" and content.get("cursorType") == "Bottom":
                    cursor = content.get("value")
                    break

                if len(list_data_twitter) >= limit:
                    break

        
        print(f"\n[#] tweets scraped: {len(list_data_twitter)}")


        if len(list_data_twitter) >= limit or cursor is None or len(entries) == 2:
            break

                    
    df_posts = pd.DataFrame(list_data_twitter)
    return df_posts
```

And here is the function code call above

```
tag_name = 'pemilu'
result_posts = get_twitter_data(tag_name)
print(result_posts)
```